# Project warnings prevent lib file from being generated

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker, warnings

During compilation, there are only warnings reported. In project settings "Treat warnings as errors" has been unchecked. But the `.lib` file is not getting generated and the linking fails. Below is my build log. Please help.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: pcwscommon, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>stdafx.cpp
1>Compiling...
1>wsxmlvld.cpp
1>e:\ws_name\eBiz\powrmart\sdk\include\sdkcmn/ivector.hpp(49) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/string.h(74) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmn2s.hpp(364) : warning C4351: new behavior: elements of array 'PmI64Str::m_buf' will be default initialized
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(280) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>        e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(298) : see reference to function template instantiation 'PM_LEN pmtFtoa<char>(double,CCC *,PM_BOOLEAN)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            CCC=char
1>        ]
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(292) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(240) : warning C4996: 'stricmp': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _stricmp. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/string.h(215) : see declaration of 'stricmp'
1>        e:\ws_name\eBiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmdate.hpp(715) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int pmtStricmpAscii<char>(const CCC *,const char *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            CCC=char
1>        ]
1>wsxmlreptbl.cpp
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmn2s.hpp(364) : warning C4351: new behavior: elements of array 'PmI64Str::m_buf' will be default initialized
1>e:\ws_name\eBiz\powrmart\sdk\include\sdkcmn/ivector.hpp(49) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/string.h(74) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(280) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>        e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(298) : see reference to function template instantiation 'PM_LEN pmtFtoa<char>(double,CCC *,PM_BOOLEAN)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            CCC=char
1>        ]
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(292) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>e:\ws_name\ebiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmtstring.hpp(240) : warning C4996: 'stricmp': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _stricmp. See online help for details.
1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\../include/string.h(215) : see declaration of 'stricmp'
1>        e:\ws_name\eBiz\powrmart\common\cmnmisc\pmdate.hpp(715) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int pmtStricmpAscii<char>(const CCC *,const char *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            CCC=char
1>        ]
1>Generating Code...
1>Linking...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'pmwscmn.lib'
1>Build log was saved at "file://e:\ws_name\eBiz\main\pcws\common\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>pcwscommon - 1 error(s), 10 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What are your projects involved? What's creating what / relying on what? What is pmwscmn.lib?/what project creates it? Your link error is with the pcwscommon project is this different?  Does this work in debug configuration?

Comment: pcwscommon is the name of the project being built itself. The project is one of many other projects in the solution, I'm selectively building this project. It is supposed to generate .lib file. Debug build also fails with the same error.

Comment: You linker is saying it can't find input 'pmwscmn.lib'. This is needed in order for the output from pcwscommon to be built. Whichever project builds 'pmwscmn.lib' either hasn't been run yet (you may be missing dependencies), or has failed, or pmwscmn.lib is a binary, that isn't in your lib path.

Comment: You are right. There is another solution file that I have to build to generate the required .lib file. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linker is saying it can't find input 'pmwscmn.lib'.

This is needed in order for the output from pcwscommon to be built.

Whichever project builds 'pmwscmn.lib' either hasn't been run yet (you may be missing dependencies), or has failed, or pmwscmn.lib is a binary, that isn't in your lib path.